# pyPDF2 picks up a extra line break in a string that I can't find or remove when parsing in python 3

Tags: python, parsing, pdf

I am trying to get data from a website pdf with python.
The website is
https://wgfd.wyo.gov/WGFD/media/content/PDF/Hunting/Drawing%20Odds/Draw_Elk_RD_Res_2010.pdf

My code imports it all into a single string and removes the header information successfully.  I am trying to build a Pandas data frame but some unusual/hidden characters are causing problems so I cant just split it into a list.  I have figured out that there are 131 characters in a the first few rows but then a hidden control character disappears resulting in the row not being parsed correctly.  I have tried removing the standard /n, /r, /t, and even /v with no luck.  The mysterious character apparently spaces down two rows.

```
pdfFileObj = open(filename,'rb')


pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

num_pages = pdfReader.numPages
text=''

#create string
for i in range(num_pages):
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
    textplus = pageObj.extractText()
    firsthunt = re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d)',textplus)
    numtoskip = textplus.find(str(firsthunt[0]))
    text += textplus[numtoskip:]
#replace charaters
text = text.replace(' ','|')
text = text.replace('/r','!')
text = text.replace('/n','#')
text = text.replace('/t','^')
text = text.replace('/v','*')
# del file    
pdfFileObj.__del__()
os.remove(filename)

rowlength = 131
for i in range(0,10):
    print(text[i*rowlength:(1+i)*rowlength])
    print('New Row')
```

Hope this makes some sense.

Thanks

Comment: Try to find the character code that is causing you problems. If necessary, print them *all* out.

Comment: I have printed with a standard print(text) command is there way to do and reveal the hidden characters?

Comment: Use `print(ord(x))` to see the character code for `x`.

Comment: I cannot access that PDF (something something *blocked* something).

Comment: its a code 10. I still haven't figured out how to remove it. replacingin  '/r' '/n' don't seam to help

Comment: i used a str.replace(chr(10,'') and it seamed to take care of it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your code did not work – I see now – because `/n` is not the correct escape code. It ought to have been `\n` ... (And the same for your other escape codes.)

Comment: You are right. That works as well.